# MySQL/ PHP/PHPMydamin error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm VERY new to PHP and MySql and like most beginners I'm trying to make use of things I'm learning so I'm trying to make a simple login/logout system.

I've downloaded WAMP,made my database in PHPMyAdmin and my table etc however I cannot get my PHP code to recognise the data in the database, I simply get 'Query failed'!I can certainly connect the database,and I don't believe the problem is with the database but my login file!I've looked at loads of different tutorial but I still can't get this to work.I'd really appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction!

If anyone wants to play around with my code thats fine the fields I have in the database are: id, username, password, first name, last name (id is a primary key with auto increment)

My login file is

```
 <?php
    //require 'core.inc.php';
    //echo $current_file;

    if (isset($_POST['username'])&& isset ($_POST['password'])){
        $username= $_POST['username'];
        $password= $_POST['password'];

        if (empty ($username)&&empty ($password)){
            echo 'supply username and password';
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM 'test1' WHERE 'username'='$username'AND 'password'='$password'";
        $result= mysql_query($query);

    if($result) {
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                //Login Successful
                session_regenerate_id();
                $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

                $_SESSION['SURNAME_NAME'] = $member['username'];
                $_SESSION['SESS_ID'] = $member['password'];
                session_write_close();

                exit();
            }else {
                //Login failed
                echo 'user name and password not found';
                $errflag = true;
                if($errflag) {
                    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
                    session_write_close();

                    exit();
                }
            }
        }else {
            die("Query failed");
        }

    }

?>

    <form method="POST">
    Username: <input type = "text" name="username"> Password: <input type ="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Log in">
    </form>
```

and my connect data base file is(I have removed my password on purpose) :

```
// assign the host user name and database name to variables
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_username = "";
$db_password = "";
$db_name = "";

session_start();
// connect to database, if not send error message
mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_username", "$db_password") or die ("Could not connect to MySQL.");
// check database exists, if not send error message
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("No database.");
// if sucessful connection etc print out the following!
//echo("Successful connection established.");
?>
```

Comment: You need to use back-ticks around your table/field names in your query... instead of single quotes

Comment: If you are new to PHP/SQL, it'll be easier for you not to learn `mysql_*` functions, rather MySQLi or PDO

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `test1` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `die('....');` with `echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error(); exit();` to see whats going on. Also do not use this example code in your real application. It's not secure since it doesn't validate input.

At least do something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bla WHERE x = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['x'])."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Alot of problems! here is a fixed code to do it right:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$database="******";
$host="localhost";
$table1="install_crawler";
$data_username="**********";
$data_password="*********";
$linkos = mysql_connect("$host", "$data_username", "$data_password") or die('no connection -'.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$database") or  die('no connection -' .mysql_error());
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username'])&& isset ($_POST['password'])) {
            $username= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
            $password= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
            if (empty ($username)&&empty ($password)) { echo 'supply username and password <br />'; } 
            else {
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table1 WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
                    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ( "Query problem!".mysql_error());         
            }
        }

if(isset($result)) {
    $member = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    if(isset($member[0])) //0 - is the first col of the table, 1 is the second etc.... 
        {
            //Login Successful - do your stuff - call your functions.
            echo "SUCCESS LOGIN!".$member[0];
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            //Login failed - do your stuff - call your functions.
            echo 'User-name Or Password NOT Correct! Try agian: <br />';
            echo '<form method="POST">
                Username: <input type = "text" name="username"> Password: <input type ="password" name="password">
                <input type="submit" value="Log in">
                </form>';
            exit;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
    echo '<form method="POST">
        Username: <input type = "text" name="username"> Password: <input type ="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Log in">
        </form>';
    }
```

Note:

1. you should use *.mysql_error()*. and add it to your DIE() statements.
2. don't use single quote while typing the table name & col's.
3. to check if a query is ok use : *$result = mysql_query($query) or die ( "Query problem!".mysql_error());*
4. use mysql_real_escape_string() to avoid and escape SQL special chars. (IMPORTANT).

See the rest in the edited code.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE username='".$username."'AND password='".$password."'";
$result= mysql_query($query);
```

I always always split my variables out from strings and append them together like above.

You may want to start with the following test after using the above

```
if($result) echo "success";
else echo mysql_error();
```

Your mysql code would be sound then. I shall point you in the direction that PHPMyAdmin has a create php code button if you create an sql statement using the sql feature.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that your 'form' tags in the example do not contain an Action parameter, perhaps this is a problem.. If it is intentional then disregard.

You should put `action="siteexample.php"` as the page where the forum data gets processed.

Does this help?

Comment: no, this is real bad practice but it will work, not providing an action will post to current page in all browsers (that I have tested)

Comment: In addition to the somesillyname's answer, a backtick looks like this:
  `

Comment: Aw darn it... I'll look for another solution !

Comment: I have submitted a edit on your answer. Please accept this, to give yourself a more professional look on this answer.

Comment: Hey everyone thank for your comment!!!I changed the tags in the query to this $query = "SELECT * FROM `test1` WHERE `username`='$username'AND `password`='$password'"; and changed quit toecho mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error(); exit();

Comment: Now a person can log in,however when I type in a wrong username I get up the echo message user name and password not found, but I also get  ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: errmsg_arr in C:\wamp\www\myfiles\login.inc.php on line 32
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0009 365584 {main}( ) ..\index.php:0
2 1.0240 385352 include( 'C:\wamp\www\myfiles\login.inc.php' ) ..\index.php:6

Comment: I think if you cannot solve login validation errors, use JavaScript for it. Jquery allows a very easy plugin that can solve your problems.
In addition, if you do <input type="email" /> then it will AUTO VALIDATE EMAILS! How nice!